# Equality of linear transformation by inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's suppose the linear transformations $A,B:E\rightarrow F$ where both $E$ and $F$ are finite dimension inner product spaces.
$$\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle Bv,w\rangle\forall w\in F,v\in E \implies A=B$$
Is this statement true? If it is, how can that be proved?

Comment: Try to take some "special" $v\in E$ and $w\in F$ to see what you can get?
 (Typo in your question by the way.)

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. Ok, i'll try it.Thanks.

Comment: @Jack in the way I see it, this can be used to get some cases where $\langle Av,w\rangle = \langle Bv,w \rangle$ for the special cases, but $A\neq B$. But does these special cases affect the general assumption? These can be cases where the equality of the intern products doesn't apply for all pairs of vectors.

Comment: By linearity, your statement is equivalent to the following: if $\langle Av,w\rangle=0$ for **all** $v,w$, then $A$ must be 0.

Comment: What "example" did you get?

Comment: @Jack i had thought of one but it wasn't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will restrict our context in the Euclidean spaces and work with matrices and column vectors. In such context, inner products can be written as matrix multiplications.

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $m\times n$ real matrix such that 
$$
v^T(Aw)=0, \text{ for all } v\in{\bf R}^m, w\in{\bf R}^n.
$$

Now consider the standard bases for ${\bf R}^m$ and ${\bf R}^n$ respectively, denoted as $\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_m\}$ and $\{\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_n\}$. Note that (check it!)
$$
a_{ij}=\alpha_i^T(A\beta_j)=0.
$$ 
So $A$ must be the zero matrix.

Comment: By replacing $A$ with $A-B$ in the calculation, you get what you want. @Rodrigo Schmidt